# Which Gita verses did Rajinikanth refer, while announcing his entry into politics?

Tags: history, bhagavad-gita, culture, translation-request, identification-request

Famous actor [Rajinikanth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajinikanth) did a grand announcement of his entry into politics on 31st December, 2017. During [his speech](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/chennai/rajnikanths-political-entry-full-text-of-his-speech/articleshow/62315921.cms), he referred Gita in following context:

> *"Karmanye Vadhikaraste Ma Phaleshu Kada Chana - Krishna (Karnan) told Arjun in Kurukshetra - Put your efforts, result is mine.  ---  (1)
>
>   Wage war, if you win you will rule the country. if you are killed in war, you will go to heaven. If you do not go to war, they will call you a coward."* ---  (2)
>   [[video source]](https://youtu.be/B1D6Clmiwsw?t=259)

- What is the translation of the Sanskrit verse "*Karmanye...*"?
- Which are the other verses in Gita related to "cowardice & waging war"?

Comment: My name comes here

Comment: @AnuragSingh The Word At The Starting karmanye is actually pronounced like my name,it is not pronounced as karmani.You can see whenever the this verse is sung.

Comment: @Karmanya Yes I know it is pronounced as Thy name. I was just telling that actually it is Sandhi of "**Karmani**" "**Eva**" which after mixing becomes "Karmanyeva". Haha. Yes. It is "Karmanya" at the end. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sanskrit verse is as following:

> **कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन।** मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि
>   BG 2.47 - **You have right only on actions; Never on [its] results;** Let not be [an agent] for results of actions; Let not be attached to inaction.

So his interpretation is correct. *"Put your efforts, result is Mine."*
Where "Mine" is the "Me" of Brahman (as referred by Krishna).

---

The other statements are also found in Gita (Gambhirananda translation):

> BG 2.36 - And **your enemies will speak many indecent words** while denigrating your might. What can be more painful than that?  (i.e. coward)
>   BG 2.37 - **Either by being killed you will attain heaven, or by winning you will enjoy the earth**. Therefore, O Arjuna, rise up with determination for fighting.

Comment: Thank you, the quote you shared helped me locate the correct source :)